# How to return index location where np.allclose() is True

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Python question, I hope someone could help me with this.
I have a list of 500+ indices of numpy array.
I want to compare that list of indices to another set of numpy array and return the index location where the value of the comparison is True.
I've looked up the np.allclose with my own tolerance to return the value of True whether two sets of arrays are similar enough.
But i don't know how to return the location of that index. I've found the list.index() function online but don't know how to implement the code for my situation

For example, I have 2 lists A and B. A has 500+ indices of numpy array in it. And B an array. I can use the np.allclose() function to return a boolean when I compare B with A. But I also want to know where in the list of A, np.allclose() returns True.

I hope the example is clear enough :D

If anyone could help, it would be great.
Thanks

Comment: np.allclose returns a single True/False answer. Did you mean np.isclose?

Comment: np.isclose will compare element by element within that array and return individual T/F for that element. I don't need it to be that precise

Let me give another example in case my previous one was not clear

Comment: Let me give another example in case my previous one was not clear
List A has 500+ indices. Each index has a set of numpy array in it.
A = [[1 1,
         2 2]
       [3 3,
        4 4]
        ......
        [n n
         n+1 n+1]]
So if I print(A[0]), I will have 
[1 1,
 2 2] and so on
B has one set of numpy array
B = [10.22 10.221]
so when I use np.allclose(A, B, rtol, atol), it will return me something like this
False
False
........
True
False
False
How can I return the location where the True value occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.nonzero` (also called `np.where`) gives indices of True elements of an array (or list:

```
In [4]: np.nonzero([False, False, True, False, False])
Out[4]: (array([2]),)
```

There are lots of SO questions about using this form of `np.where`.